# Как в Android Studio собрать .aar?

Tags: android-studio

Есть макро-библиотека (кастомный `View` из одного класса и одной разметки. Каким образом из них можно собрать aar, подключаемый к проекту? Есть id-шники, мне что, самому R.java писать? Или как?

Comment: Нужно создать library project. После его сборки в `build/outputs/aar/` появится `aar`-файл.

Comment: Спасибо, оформите ответом

Comment: А какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы создать библиотеку, нужно добавить в проект модуль соответствующего типа:

```
File > New > New Module – Android Library.
```

Далее, после сборки этого модуля, в папке `build\outputs\aar` появится `*.aar`-файл.